# Handling artifacts changing groupID and transitive dependency risk

Tags: java, maven, classpath, nexus

When a Maven artifact for some reason change groupId and the developers do not update package name accordingly, classpath conflicts can emerge. Let's imagine a build like the following:

- `artifact2`

  - depends on `com.bla v2` and uses classes `xyz.MyClass`
- `artifact1`

  - depends on `org.bla v1` and uses classes `xyz.MyClass`

When we run our "main" with the full classpath, it might happen that when class from `artifact1` using `xyz.MyClass` is firstly loaded, `xyz.MyClass` is resolved from com.bla instead that org.bla

Does Nexus Sonatype or other tools for application lifecycle management help identify this problems, for example, before promoting a build to release?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Maven Enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/index.html) for this, using the "Ban Duplicate Classes" rule from the [Extra Enforcer Rules](http://mojo.codehaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/banDuplicateClasses.html).

So this would be a POM-level fix and should affect anything that builds from that POM. Your project would not build if duplicate classes are found.

Answer (score 1):

Sonatype Nexus Professional CLM Edition can define policies based on GAV coordinates and then enforce them in a release build. You have to define them manually yourself once you are aware of these changes. There is no automatic detection.

The policies can use a whole lot of different rules that you can define e.g. certain GAV coordinates are not allowed, artifacts of certain age are not allowed, artifacts with know security vulnerabilities of severity > 5 not allowed and so on.

With Sonatype CLM you can then also enforce and report on these policies in Eclipse, Hudons, Jenkins, Bamboo, Sonarqube and command line tools.

Like Duncan mentions you can also use the Enforcer plugin. If you do that I suggest to move invocation into a separate profile since larger checks have a big build performance impact. And to use it across your organization you can configure it in a parent pom for your organization.

Comment: The policies sounds very interesting, how they will prevent having duplicate classnames?